# Upgraded DOCTYPE to html5-compliant, but I can't figure out where three extra pixels came from

Tags: css, html

I updated DOCTYPE in our application and layout in some of the widget got broken.
In one list there was no scrollbar before, but now there is a scrollbar and I can't figure out why (This particular issue can be reproduced in Chrome).
I created one simple example to illustrate the problem:

```
  <div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: 152px; height: 60px;">
     <div >
        <div style="display: inline-block;" style="width: 152px;">
           <div style="width: 152px; height: 20px;overflow: hidden;">Item</div>
           <div style="width: 152px; height: 20px;overflow: hidden;">Item</div>
           <div style="width: 152px; height: 20px;overflow: hidden;">Item</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is jsfiddle with transitional doctype where list displayed normally: https://jsfiddle.net/vmga/sL04vjwd/

And the same code, but with html5 doctype there is a scrollbar: https://jsfiddle.net/vmga/aus0tp8p/

Chrome dev tools shows that height of the parent container (div) is 64px:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Where those 4 extra pixels came from?
2. How to debug such issues? Chrome just shows final number, but there is no insight about how this number was calculated. How this problems should be approached?

Comment: Are you sure that selected div does not have height: 64px property?

Comment: Why do you even have those properties on the inner `<div>`s? There is no need. `<div>` is by default `display: block;` and the way you're using them, there is no reason to use the `display: inline-block;` and the set `width` on any of the innter containers. Also, that should be a list `<ul><li></li></ul>`, not a bunch of `<div>`s

Comment: That is simplified version that still demonstrate the problem, real html is more complex. And it is what it is, it is legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

display:inline-block creates margin in HTML5. I've seen it cause other mystery right added space in other versions.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. is some reliable way to deduce it? Or maybe some document? or some debugging tool? And why I wasn't able to reproduce it in Firefox? Right now it just feels like some blackbox and sacred knowledge :(  (I acknowledge that I'm not a css ninja, but still ...)

Comment: You know... one issue all of us front-end folks have is the various browsers interpret code a little differently and they have their own little quirks. It becomes a learned knowledge as you get more and more experience working on the front end. But the best way to deduce is to use your developer tools in chrome and in Firefox. Inspect the elements and disable styles one by one. Or sometimes you will be adding styles one by one :o)